# Python - como criar planilha no excel (com 100 colunas)

Tags: python-3.x, microsoft-excel, planilha

Boa tarde!

Eu já sei criar uma planilha no Excel pelo Python, quando eu sei exatamente quais colunas eu preciso criar.
Mas como eu posso fazer, para que a criação de colunas seja dinâmica?
por exemplo:

para criar uma planilha simples, eu utilizo a biblioteca workbook e faço assim:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook

book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active
nome_xlsx = 'teste.xlsx'

sheet['A1'] = 'ID1'
sheet['B1'] = 'ID2'
sheet['C1'] = 'ID3'
sheet['D1'] = 'ID4'
sheet['E1'] = 'ID5'
lista_de_ordenacao = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
cont = 2
for item in lista_de_ordenacao:
    item1 = item[0]
    sheet['A'+str(cont)] = int(item1)
    item2 = item[1]
    sheet['B'+str(cont)] = str(item2)
    item3 = item[2]
    sheet['C'+str(cont)] = str(item3)
    item4 = item[3]
    sheet['D'+str(cont)] = str(item4)
    item5 = item[4]
    sheet['E'+str(cont)] = str(item5)
    cont = cont + 1

book.save(nome_xlsx)
```

Mas, como eu faria para criar por exemplo, 100 colunas de forma que eu nao precise digitar manualmente no código `sheet['CV1'] = 'qualquer coisa'`?

No meu caso, eu preciso fazer varias planilhas com matrizes, então, algumas podem ter 100 linhas e 100 colunas, outras podem ter 1000 linhas e 1000 colunas

Esse valor varia conforme os dados que eu preciso colocar na matriz

Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido! Não sei se essa foi a melhor forma de resolver, mas consegui desenvolver assim:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import string

book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active
nome_xlsx = 'teste.xlsx'

listax=[]
abrir_aquivo = open('DADOS.txt', 'r' ,encoding='utf8')
lista_seguindo_usuario = abrir_aquivo.read()
listax = lista_seguindo_usuario.split('\n')
abrir_aquivo.close()
usuario_principal = listax[0]
del(listax[0])
numero_seguindo = int(listax[0])
del(listax[0])


lista = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
lista2 = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
lista2.insert(0,'A')
aux = 0
cont = 0
flag = 0
x=1
numero_seguindo = numero_seguindo + 1
while cont != numero_seguindo:
    print(cont)
    aux2 = lista2[0]
    if aux == (len(lista)):
        aux = 0
        flag = 1
        del(lista2[0])
        aux2 = lista2[0]
    if aux < len(lista)  and flag == 0:
        sheet[str(lista[aux]) + str(x)] = listax[0]
        aux = aux + 1
    if aux < len(lista) and flag == 1:
        sheet[aux2 + str(lista[aux]) + str(x)] = listax[0]
        aux = aux + 1
    cont = cont + 1
    sheet['A'+str(cont+1)] = listax[0]
    del(listax[0])    
sheet['A1'] = 'MATRIZ'



book.save(nome_xlsx)
```

PS:na segunda linha do txt tem o numero de colunas e linhas que eu preciso fazer :)